# How to properly use Galilean transformation in order to move between inertial frames?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

I'm having trouble understanding how to use Galilean transform when moving between coordinates. e.g consider the following problem: a mass attached to a spring inside a moving cart - how can I represent the coordinates of the cart and the mass from the different inertial frames - the laboratory frame and the cart frame.

[image]

If I try to find the coordinates of the mass from inside the cart, I thought they should look something like (x,0) in contrast to when I look from the laboratory inertial frame:

[image]

It'll be (x+v_0 t,0) and if I want to talk about the cart's location then I can denote it's coordinates as (x', y')

how can I generalize this, I get confused sometimes between the cases where I need to add v0*t or subtract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential thing you need here is the relation between the displacement vectors between $2$ different reference frames.

Let the point $P$ has position vector $\vec r|_{O}$ in the reference frame $O$ and $\vec r|_{O'}$ in frame $O'$. Let the position vector of the origin of $O$ with respect to the origin of $O'$ be $\vec {O'O}$. Then, we have - 
$$\vec r|_{O'} = \vec r|_{O} + \vec {O'O}$$
that is, position wrt origin of $O =$ position wrt origin of $O'+$ position of origin of $O'$ wrt origin of $O'$.

So, in your case, as reference frame $O$ is moving at velocity $v$ wrt $O'$, we have $\vec {O'O} = v_0t$. Thus, $x' = x + v_0t$.
The others follow similarly.

Comment: I think I understand better now. thank you!